# Get response using pdo sql?

Tags: sql, database, select, pdo, prepared-statement

I am trying to get the actual response (the data) from my database using prepared statements:

```
$stmt=$dbconn->prepare("SELECT user_videos FROM public.account_recover_users WHERE user_mail= :email");
$stmt->execute(array(':videos'=>$json_videos,':email'=>$email));
```

I know that `$stmt->execute(array(':videos'=>$json_videos,':email'=>$email));` will return a boolean, not the actual data. But how to get the data from my database into an array? I will need to later return that data, the script is accessed via a `GET` request, and I will need to do `exit("{'data':$data_from_db}");` so I don't want to fetch each row using `foreach($stmt as $row)`. Just pass it all as it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
$results = array();

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $results[] = $row;
}
```